# Why is Laravel verification email URL is not working?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, verification

I am using **Laravel 9** with the defaul email verification.
I implemented **MustVerifyEmail** to the user class in User model, and I set the other configurations and it worked perfectly.

Now I wanted to *queue* sending the verification email (because it takes sometime if we send it directly after the user registers which is not a good user experience).

so what I did is implementing **ShouldQueue** in *~/Auth/Notifications/VerifyEmail.php* to become like this:

```
class VerifyEmail extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;
    ...
    }
```

this also worked and queues were made.. BUT ... the the verification URL sent in the email was different than the one before implementing the queue; for example.. a working URL like:

http://localhost/laravel/test3/public/email/verify/8/0065f1dcb247eb5698c48b9f29cf954bb4281293?expires=1661746205&signature=0bd0b91c5c4b6f315084aea4727247edecc51de6abd94c0064dd5b3ca13c8e25

and non-working URL (after implementing the Queue):
http://localhost/email/verify/10/13e97097f849755e407241c5765eb5853106229b?expires=1661746916&signature=703aaecf0061b8939682270cfdfbcf24bc70c5473418116f00f5eb063b817651

so the first part of the link was removed (laravel/test3/public/email), and even if I add it to the link manually it will give ***Invalid signature*** .. maybe because it is a *temporary Signed URL*.

**so the question is: How can we change the link to be correctly working ?**

p.s: I found this in **VerifyEmail.php** but I didn't know how to change it..

```
protected function verificationUrl($notifiable)
    {
        if (static::$createUrlCallback) {
            return call_user_func(static::$createUrlCallback, $notifiable);
        }

        return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
            'verification.verify',
            Carbon::now()->addMinutes(Config::get('auth.verification.expire', 60)),
            [
                'id' => $notifiable->getKey(),
                'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
            ]
        );
    }
```

Comment: Since queueing uses a queue worker which is essentially a console application you should set your .env variable `APP_URL=http://localhost/laravel/test3/public` otherwise it will use the default `http://localhost/`

Answer (score 0):

You can customize this URL in `web.php`, but route name and variable name should be exact to previous.

```
Route::get('/laravel/test3/public/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', [ EmailVerificationController::class, 'verify' ])
    ->middleware(['auth', 'signed', 'throttle:6,1'])
    ->name('verification.verify');
```